# Parent Child Named Pipe WCF service within the same process issue

Tags: wcf, impersonation, named-pipes

I'm having a strange issue when I host two named pipe WCF services within the same process with one communicating with the other. One of the services is a parent singleton that holds a proxy to multiple child persession instances. I'm hosting them both on process startup using named pipe end points. Everything works fine but when I enabled impersonation on both of the services I get an endpoint not found exception in the parent to child proxy creation. Any idea why impersonation would be causing this to fail?

Comment: I've tried to repro this but failed... the scenario works for me. Pls could you post some code showing how you are (1) creating and using the proxies (2) configuring for impersonation?

Comment: Also, re "...parent singleton that holds a proxy to multiple child persession instances." ... I don't know how you can have done this: One proxy => one pipe => one session, I would have thought.

Comment: I ended up abandoning the approach and using IIS as the host and using http endpoints. Once I have some down time I'll see if I can get the named pipes code running again and post the source code.